# Type has no member during Apple tutorial

Tags: swift

I just started learning **Swift**. I am following [this Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) but I was met with this error. I copied the exact code from the tutorial. Not sure where did I go wrong.

Error message:

> "Type 'RatingControl' has no member 'ratingButtonTapped(button:)'"

```
//Mark: Private Methods
private func setupButtons() {
    for _ in 0..<5 {
        //Create the button
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        //Add constraints
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

        //Setup the button action
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        //Add the button to the stack
        addArrangedSubview(button)

        //Add the new button to the rating button array
        ratingButtons.append(button)
    }
}
```

Comment: A typo, maybe? Adding this method is definitely part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial to get the button action the `RatingControl.swift` class will be like

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RatingControl: UIStackView {

    //MARK: Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
     }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
     }

    //MARK: Button Action

   @objc func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")
    }

}
```

Create a file named `RatingControl.swift` with code and run your project. This issue will be resolved.

if you already have the full class the just add `@objc` before the method `ratingButtonTapped`.

**More info:** You can download the full project of the tutorial you currently following. The download link is present at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

We truly need to see the whole `RatingControl` class in order give you a complete answer. However your problem based on the error is that you there is no function with the name `ratingButtonTapped` inside your `RatingControl` class. There should be a class like the following in order to register it as a target to a button.

Example of `.addTarget` usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Setup the button action
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }


    @objc func ratingButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
       // Triggered when the button is pressed
    }
}
```